# Importing images from the web using ImportString & URLFetch

Tags: bugs, import, web-access

I can bring images from the web using the Import command like this:

```
Import["http://blog.wolfram.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/se-30.jpg"]
```

[image: good image]

Sometimes the web request is more complicated so I must to use URLFetch. For that, this is what I have tried to do:

```
ImportString[
    URLFetch["http://blog.wolfram.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/se-30.jpg"],
"JPG"]
```

[image: unreadable image]

Do you know how to make the image load correctly? I suspect that this is related to strings encodings, but I have not been able to solve it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a bug due to the fact that `URLFetch` is dealing incorrectly with line breaks.  Here's a workaround:

```
in1 = URLFetch[
  "http://blog.wolfram.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/se-30.jpg", 
  "ContentData"
];
ImportString[FromCharacterCode[in1]]
```

You can compare this technique to the other as follows:

```
in2 = ToCharacterCode[URLFetch[
  "http://blog.wolfram.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/se-30.jpg"]
];
SequenceAlignment[in1, in2]
```