# Importing malformed XML: Import[... "XMLObject"] vs ImportString[..., "XML"]

Tags: import, xml

It appears that `Import[ url , "XMLObject" ]` is more forgiving of improperly formatted XML than `ImportString[ string, "XML"]`. For example, Mathematica is happy to do this

```
popNamesXML = 
  Import["http://uscode.house.gov/popularnames/popularnames.htm", 
    "XMLObject"];
```

but complains about this

```
popNames = 
  URLFetch["http://uscode.house.gov/popularnames/popularnames.htm"];
xml = ImportString[popNames, "XML"];
```

[image]

and barks about utf8 encoding for this

```
ImportString[popNames, {"HTML", "XMLObject"}]
```

In the `Trace` of the first snippet it appears these options are being passed to `XMLGetString`:

```
{"NormalizeWhitespace"->True,"IncludeNamespaces"->Automatic,
 "ValidateAgainstDTD"->Automatic,"IncludeEmbeddedObjects"->None,
 "AllowRemoteDTDAccess"->True,"ReadDTD"->True,"IncludeDefaultedAttributes"->False,
 "AllowUnrecognizedEntities"->Auomatic,"PreserveCDATASections"->False}
```

But passing these to `ImportString` or directly to `XMLGetString` still results in the same errors.

[This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25149/5059) may be of interest but does not seem to be the problem, though I could be wrong. I tinkered with the suggestion there without luck. Does anyone know if/how I can make `ImportString` behave nicely here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am using Mathematica 8.0.4 and have no `URLFetch` command, so I have used [Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) to download this 5915505 bytes file:

```
wget http://uscode.house.gov/popularnames/popularnames.htm
```

After downloading I evaluated

```
popNamesXML = Import["popularnames.htm", "XMLObject"]
```

And got the `XMLObject` without any errors. Then I `Import`ed this file as `"Text"` and tried to get the `XMLObject` using `ImportString`:

```
popNames = Import["popularnames.htm", "Text"];
ImportString[popNames, {"HTML", "XMLObject"}]
```

I got a couple if the `$CharacterEncoding::utf8` errors on the last step, instead of the `XMLObject` I got the plaintext version of the page.

So it is clear at least that the problem is not in `URLFetch` but in `ImportString` itself. I think it is worth to report it to Wolfram Support.

One workaround is to `Export` the `popNames` into a file with extension .htm, then `Import` it:

```
Export["popNames.htm", popNames, "Text"]
popNamesXML = Import["popNames.htm", "XMLObject"]
```

It poduces the desired `XMLObject`.

Another workaround is to use `CharacterEncoding -> "WindowsANSI"` option:

```
popNamesXML2 = ImportString[popNames, {"XHTML", "XMLObject"}, CharacterEncoding -> "WindowsANSI"]
```

It produces identical `XMLObject` without errors:

```
popNamesXML2 === popNamesXML
```

> ```
> True
> ```

So the problem is that `ImportString` by default incorrectly chooses the `"UTF8"` encoding instead of `"WindowsANSI"`. It looks like a bug since it is not related to global `$CharacterEncoding` variable: setting

```
$CharacterEncoding = "WindowsANSI"
```

does not change anything.

On the Documentation page for the `"HTML"` format we read:

> If the character encoding of the file is not specified in the HTML
>   file, `Import` uses the encoding specified by `CharacterEncoding`. A
>   complete list of possible encodings is given by `$CharacterEncodings`.

This statement seems to be misleading for two reasons:

1) The default value for `CharacterEncoding` is `Automatic` and it is not clear how `ImportString` should behave in the case when character encoding is not specified in the HTML file.

2) In our case the character encoding IS specified in the HTML file on the first and fourth lines AND IS ignored when we provide explicit value for the `CharacterEncoding` option:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Manually deleting the "encoding='UTF-8'" and "charset=UTF-8" from the file in a plain text editor does fix incorrect behavior: now we get identical `XMLObject` without errors:

```
popNamesXML === ImportString[Import["popularnames_fixed.htm", "Text"], {"XHTML", "XMLObject"}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

I have also checked the server response (which should also contain the encoding information) using the `-S` switch of Wget:

```
wget -S http://uscode.house.gov/popularnames/popularnames.htm
```

and got

> Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8

It means `Import` gets no correct information about encoding from the server but is able to determine the correct encoding in this case.

So the final diagnosis is similar to what [mfvonh](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5059/mfvonh) suggested: `Import` can automatically handle the cases when incorrect encoding is specified in an HTML file while `ImportString` in such cases needs the correct encoding specified through the `CharacterEncoding` option.

Comment: Interesting. I passed the page to the [W3 Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) and got what appeared to be the same (25,000+) errors. Deleting the encoding lines and specifying ANSI (Windows-1252) made no difference; got the same errors. Sublime Text tells me the downloaded file (using wget) is UTF-8. Do you think this file is actually ANSI? I don't know how to check that other than relying on Sublime/etc. or counting bytes manually.

Comment: I cannot be sure that the page is actually ANSI. May be it is UTF-8 but contains only ASCII symbols so there is no difference. As I understand *Mathematica* internally cannot store true UTF-8 and after `Import`ing it becomes pure ANSI.